# Error CS1601 from ASP.NET Application, but can't see why

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working my way through this tutorial [here](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/themes/progress-bar-csharp.aspx) about progress dialogues but have hit an elementary problem I can't see the cause of. The my project so far returns the error message...

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.webprogressbar_aspx' does not contain a
definition for 'Button1_Click' and no extension method 'Button1_Click' accepting
a first argument of type 'ASP.webprogressbar_aspx' could be found (are you
missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 12:     <legend>WebProgressBar</legend>
Line 13:     <div>
Line 14:       <asp:Button id="Button1"
Line 15:                   runat="server"
Line 16:                   Text="Start Long Task!"
```

The project so far is (in its entirety), the WebProgressBar.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"
         AutoEventWireup="true"
         CodeBehind="WebProgressBar.aspx.cs"%>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title> </title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <fieldset>
   <legend>WebProgressBar</legend>
    <div>
      <asp:Button id="Button1"
                  runat="server"
                  Text="Start Long Task!"
                  OnClick="Button1_Click">
      </asp:Button>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the WebProgressBar.aspx.cs...

```
using System;

public partial class WebProgressBar : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["State"] = 1;
    }

}
```

Can anyone see what I have overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to be missing the tag to inherit a class. Essentially it can't find the event handlers for your button since the class hasn't been listed.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="WebProgressBar" CodeBehind="WebProgressBar.aspx.cs"%>
```

Comment: I have a same problem I just add what you mentioned but now the err is:  Could not load type 'WebProgressBar'

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing the `Inherits` attribute in your `<%@ Page` statement.

```
<%@ Page ... Inherits="WebProgressBar" %>
```