# asp.net web form button onclick event error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have asp.net web form and when Im trying to assing onclick event to a button I get following error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.webform1_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button1_Click' and no extension method 'Button1_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.webform1_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 19:      Line 20:      Line 21:     
>   Line 22:         
>   Line 23:

ASP code is following:

```
     <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server" method="post">
    <div class="page">
    <p>Persons</p>
    <asp:Literal  id="drpdwn"  runat="server" /> 
    <p>TransactionType</p>
    <select id="sel" runat="server"> 
        <option>bilance </option>
        <option>liekākais parādnieks un aizdevējs</option>
        <option>vidējais aizņēmuma lielums</option>
    </select>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <table id="HTMLTable" width="300px;" runat="server">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b></b>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var yourSelect = document.getElementById("sel");
    var asdasd = yourSelect.options[yourSelect.selectedIndex].value;
</script>
</html>
```

And Codebehind is following:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //int selectedIndex = (sel as HtmlSelect).SelectedIndex;
            sel.Value.ToString();
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
            SqlDataReader rdr = null;
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            cnn.ConnectionString = @"Server=localhost;Database=TildeTest;uid=AdminUser;pwd=AdminPwd;app=WebApplication1;";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string CommandText = "select * from persons";
            command = new SqlCommand(CommandText);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            //command.Connection = cnn;
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                command.Connection = cnn;
                rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    drpdwn.Text = "<select>";
                    drpdwn.Text += "<option> </option>";
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        drpdwn.Text += "<option>" + rdr.GetString(1) + "</option>";
                    }
                    drpdwn.Text += "</select>";
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
                }
                rdr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    cnn.Close();
            }

        }
        void Button1_Click(Object sender,
                                  EventArgs e)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924061/error-cs1601-from-asp-net-application-but-cant-see-why

Comment: Solution doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using visual studio, double click the button from design view, then write the code behind inside the generated function. That should work.

Comment: This solution worked! Visual Studio generated the same code but somehow it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can change `void Button1_Click` to `protected void Button1_Click` and try.